# Automated way to push new releases and bug fixes to all repositories calling our workflows?

Tags: github-actions

I am developing github workflows in a centralized repository for use by other app teams repositories within our organization.

All of these calling repositories have a main.yml (for push action) and a pull-request.yml (for pull-request-actions). Within these files, these repositories are calling individual workflows in this format:

```
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-A.yml@v1
```

where example-repo contains a release-tag called 'v1'

I am currently working on an automated way to open a PR to these calling repos for new releases and bug-fix versions.

The ay I'm thinking of doing it is:

1. creating an trigger for release tag creation
2. looping through all repos in our org
3. Checking for existance of .github/workflows dir (not all repos in org are making use of our workflows yet)
4. If found, checking for the call to our workflows
5. Opening a PR if this workflow tag-ref requires an update.

Is this a good way to go about this? Is there something more preferable? I was hoping to set some kind of org-level $RELEASE_VERSION variable, but it seems these vars cannot be evaluated on a workflow call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to refer a branch instead of a release. For example:

```
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-A.yml@stable
```

And then your teams will pull from the `stable` branch.

The other approach is what you mentioned, have a trigger on tag creation and then have a GitHub bot committing in all of your repositories.

---

Edit:

There are already some actions like [`BetaHuhn/repo-file-sync-action`](https://github.com/BetaHuhn/repo-file-sync-action) you may want to have a look at them as well